# new font size stops getting bigger at a certain limit in article

Tags: fontsize

I defined a new font size using this command

`\newcommand{\Hone}[1]{{\fontsize{2em}{2.2em}\selectfont\textbf{#1}}}`

but I noticed that it is not applied for all sizes

what I mean by that is for example if I change `2em` to `50em` or to `100em` the font will be the same

this is how I'm using the command

`\Hone{test}`

why is this happening?

Comment: `\usepackage{fix-cm}` in the preamble should work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the package `fix-cm` to the preamble:

[image]

```
\RequirePackage{fix-cm}
\documentclass{article}

%\usepackage{fix-cm} % if T1 encoding is used

\newcommand{\HoneTwo}[1]{{\fontsize{2em}{2.2em}\selectfont\textbf{#1}}}
\newcommand{\HoneFive}[1]{{\fontsize{5em}{2.2em}\selectfont\textbf{#1}}}
\newcommand{\HoneTen}[1]{{\fontsize{10em}{2.2em}\selectfont\textbf{#1}}}

\begin{document}
\HoneTwo{Text at 2.2em}\\
\HoneFive{Text at 5em}\\
\HoneTen{Text at 10em}
\end{document}
```

Comment: It's better `\RequirePackage{fix-cm}` before `\documentclass` if the T1 encoding is not used.